# How can I improve the performance of zipping files from a remote directory?

Tags: c#, iis, zip, .net-4.5, remote-server

The application needs to zip up some log files in memory from a remote inetpub\LogFiles\W3SVCXX folder. The application will then extract the zip to a local directory for parsing. This is the code for this:

```
    public static string ArchiveFiles(List<string> filePathsToArchive, string siteName, string chartId)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update,true))
            {
                int index = 0;
                foreach (var filePath in filePathsToArchive)
                {
                    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(filePath, index.ToString() + ".log");  //this line is taking forever when using a remote folder

                    index++;
                }
                var dir = CreateOrGetDirectory(ARCHIVE_DIRECTORY+ siteName+ @"\" + chartId + @"\");
                archive.ExtractToDirectory(dir.FullName);
                return dir.FullName;
            }
        }
    }
```

It is incredibly inefficient on archive.CreateEntryFromFile() when I pass it a remote folder (works fine when the log files are on my local machine).

Is there any way that to optimize this when zipping up files from a remote location?

Comment: Why zip the files in the first place if the very next step is to extract them?  Why not just copy the files directly?  If you need to retain a zip for some other downstream purpose then perform the zip after copying them locally, since you say that works well with local files.

Comment: Are you simply trying to preserve network bandwidth? The only way you can do that is to zip on the remote server.

Comment: Agree that copy files locally, zip, and than extract is "incredibly inefficient", but it is not clear what your actual goal is so it is hard to suggest useful improvements.

Comment: You could use a BufferedInputStream instead of the file directly. That assumes you there exists a method such as AddEntryFromStream. The other solution is to use a set of worker threads to copy the files locally on the file system or in memory while the main thread compresses them.

Comment: Hi,

The goal is to get the log files onto my my app server so that I can parse them and display the data on a dashboard / create reports with it using excel.

Comment: As David said, if I skip zipping them up and copying them directly, I would use up more network bandwidth so I was trying to avoid that. I tested it and it's definitely faster(copies about 40 files in a couple of minutes). From a web perspective, it would be too long for a user to wait for a chart to render which will show Total Requests for the past month. Since our environment has 2 production servers, it would be pulling logs from both servers for each day before I parse them, and thats over 60 files at least (1 per day per server).